# Defer Layout Update of PivotTable

Tags: vba, excel, ssas

I am creating some VBA Functions in Excel to build some PivotTable templates off of an Analysis Services Cube. For speed of execution and updating, I would like to use the functionality of the check box for Defer Layout Update. I expect the fields to be added all at once and then update at the end of the `With` block. I have tried:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(ptName)
    .ManualUpdate = True
    .CubeFields("[Fiscal Week Code - Last Week]").Orientation = xlColumnField
    .CubeFields("[DimDate].[Date]").Orientation = xlRowField
    .ManualUpdate = False
End With
```

But the ManualUpdate Property isn't working appropriately according to this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823168.aspx) article. MSDN says it is a read/write property, and the object browser doesn't mention it being a read-only property.

I also tried with a PivotTable that is connected to a spreadsheet for the source data and the property didn't work there either.

Thanks in advance!

-Wyatt

Comment: I'm experiencing the same behavior.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Travis not really a work around, but  you can turn off screen updating. That only helps the looks, not the speed though.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up turning to Power Query to get the needed data from the SSAS cube which avoided the filtering change problems I was having.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with ManualUpdate has been equally frustrating. There appear to be some actions where it doesn't work.

My only advice would be to try setting  ManualUpdate = True before each individual action that changes the pivot. So in your code put ManualUpdate = True before each line that says CubeFields. I have had some success that way.

Comment: I timed this by logging the start and end time of adding the `CubeFields . It didn't make any difference to include `ManualUpdate=True` before each action.